# Any way to catch the notifications so another program can read them?

Tags: notification, ruby, notify-osd, libnotify

I know you can see notifications in the terminal using `dbus-monitor "interface='org.freedesktop.Notifications'" | grep --line-buffered  "string"`, but is there any easy way to catch the notifications and send them to a running application?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a ruby developer, came across this question while looking to do the same thing with Python - for Ruby, you might want to check out https://github.com/mvidner/ruby-dbus for this.

For python I'm using the python-dbus package now which is working great :)